# How can I find the Optimal Price Point and Group By ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'ID':[101762, 101762, 101762, 101762, 102842, 102842, 102842, 102842, 108615, 108615, 108615, 108615, 108615, 108615],
        'Year':[2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
        'Quantity':[60, 80, 88, 75, 50, 55, 62, 58, 100, 105, 112, 110, 98, 95],
        'Price':[2000, 3000, 3330, 4000, 850, 900, 915, 980, 1000, 1250, 1400, 1550, 1600, 1850]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
        ID  Year  Quantity  Price
0   101762  2019        60   2000
1   101762  2019        80   3000
2   101762  2019        88   3330
3   101762  2019        75   4000
4   102842  2020        50    850
5   102842  2020        55    900
6   102842  2020        62    915
7   102842  2020        58    980
8   108615  2021       100   1000
9   108615  2021       105   1250
10  108615  2021       112   1400
11  108615  2021       110   1550
12  108615  2021        98   1600
13  108615  2021        95   1850
```

Here are some plots of the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
uniques = df['ID'].unique()

for i in uniques:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(4,3)
    df_single = df[df['ID']==i]
    sns.lineplot(data=df_single, x='Price', y='Quantity')
    ax.set(xlabel='Price', ylabel='Quantity')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I am trying to find the optimal price to sell something, before quantity sold starts to decline. I think the code below is pretty close, but when I run the code I get '33272.53'. This doesn't make any sense. I am trying to get the optimal price point per ID. How can I do that?

```
df["% Change in Quantity"] = df["Quantity"].pct_change()
df["% Change in Price"] = df["Price"].pct_change()
df["Price Elasticity"] = df["% Change in Quantity"] / df["% Change in Price"]
df.columns


import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = df[["Price"]]
y = df["Quantity"]


# Fit a linear regression model to the data
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

# Find the optimal price that maximizes the quantity sold
optimal_price = reg.intercept_/reg.coef_[0]
optimal_price
```

Comment: Setting aside the "grouping" concept for a second, it isn't clear what you are looking for.  In the example, for "stadium" you have several (transactions?) on one day for different quantities and prices.  If they are sequential (not clear), do you just want to find the row where the quantity declines relative to previous?  What is the intent with the regression model?

Comment: Do you expect `optimal_price` to be `70` for both ids ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be some fraction of a number between 70 & 65 for Stadium, and some fraction of a number between 70 & 68 for Casino? Also, what if it increases and decreases multiple times for Stadium and increases and decreases multiple times for Casino? I'm pretty sure it requires some kind of regression solution, or optimization solution. I don't know how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: In both of those cases, the price is still going up....  so why sell?  This problem is not well described and the role of linear regression in this isn't clear at all.

Comment: I refactored my problem statement. I can do a simple GroupBy Max, and get the max per group.
df.groupby(['ID','Year'])['Price'].max()

I am hoping to find some kind of statistics-related solution, or regression solution, or something along these lines.